# Lisp translation

Tags: python, math, lisp, autolisp

I need a Lisp algorithm translated to either Python or a math equation. Does any have the required skills to do so?

```
;; Bulge Center  -  Lee Mac
;; p1 - start vertex
;; p2 - end vertex
;; b  - bulge
;; Returns the center of the arc described by the given bulge and vertices

(defun LM:BulgeCenter ( p1 p2 b )
    (polar p1
        (+ (angle p1 p2) (- (/ pi 2) (* 2 (atan b))))
        (/ (* (distance p1 p2) (1+ (* b b))) 4 b)
    )
)
```

Comment: the idea is: operators or functions come first, then the arguments. Just rewrite by putting them into the proper order. Ex: `(+ (angle p1 p2) (- (/ pi 2) (* 2 (atan b))))` => `((angle(p1,p2) + ((pi /2) - (2 * (atan (b))))`  (I didn't count the parentheses)

Comment: alright. i'll do that. thank you for the example!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `1+` is a standard Lisp  function which adds 1 to its argument.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. My lisp is a bit rusty/limited to amiga installer script :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: > *"Does any have the required skills to do so"*  I would say, pretty much anyone who can guess that (f x y) is the same as f(x, y).

Answer (score 3):

Infix notation would look similar to this:

```
polar(p1,
      angle(p1,p2) + ( pi / 2 - 2 * atan(b)),
      (distance(p1,p2) * (1 + b * b)) / (4 * b)
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty function to prettify it:

```
(ql:quickload :trivia)
(use-package :trivia)

(defun pretty (form)
  (match form
    ('pi "\\pi{}")
    ((or 'p1 'p2) (format nil
                          "~{~(~a~)_{~a}~}"
                          (coerce (string form) 'list)))
    ((type symbol) (let ((name (string-downcase (string form))))
                     (if (= (length name) 1)
                         name
                         (format nil "\\text{~a}" name))))
    ((type number) (princ-to-string form))
    ((list '1+ x) (pretty `(+ ,x 1)))
    ((list* '* args) (if (= (length (remove-duplicates args)) 1)
                         (format nil
                                 "~a^{~a}"
                                 (pretty (first args))
                                 (length args))
                         (format nil
                                 "~{~a~^\\cdot{}~}"
                                 (mapcar #'pretty args))))
    ((list '/ x) (pretty `(/ 1 ,x)))
    ((list '/ x y) (format nil
                           "\\frac{~a}{~a}"
                           (pretty x)
                           (pretty y)))
    ((list* '/ x args) (pretty `(/ ,x (* ,@args))))
    ((list* (guard op (member op '(+ -))) args)
     (with-output-to-string (out)
       (loop
         initially (princ "\\left(" out)
         for (a . b) on args
         do (princ (pretty a) out)
         while b
         do (format out " ~a " op)
         finally (princ "\\right)" out))))
    ((list* op args) (format nil
                             "~a\\left(~{~a~^, ~}\\right)"
                             (pretty op)
                             (mapcar #'pretty args)))))
```

Call that on the quoted expression to obtain a LaTeX math expression.
For example, under Emacs/Slime, <kbd>C-u C-x e</kbd> after the following form evaluates and inserts the output in the same buffer (you could use the REPL too):

```
(progn
  (princ
        (pretty 
         '(polar p1
           (+ (angle p1 p2) (- (/ pi 2) (* 2 (atan b))))
           (/ (* (distance p1 p2) (1+ (* b b))) 4 b)
           )))
  (values))
```

You can then include the string in a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{polar}\left(p_{1}, \left(\text{angle}\left(p_{1}, p_{2}\right) + \left(\frac{\pi{}}{2} - 2\cdot{}\text{atan}\left(b\right)\right)\right), \frac{\text{distance}\left(p_{1}, p_{2}\right)\cdot{}\left(b^{2} + 1\right)}{4\cdot{}b}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Note: if you do not want to install LaTeX, use e.g. http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php or http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor.

Comment: you're definitely having fun. :) :) (the dot is too low though, both on IE and Firefox, for some reason)

Comment: @WillNess Yes, it was fun. As for the dot, this can easily be replaced by `\cdot{}` or `\times{}`.

Comment: You should typeset symbol names like `distance` using `\text`, I think.  Otherwise basically you're  typesetting *distance* as a product term combining eight variables.

Comment: @Kaz I changed the whole thing to use trivia, since it is becoming a full-time project 
 ;-)